# Apache2: lock down locations without opening up the front controller index.php

Tags: laravel, apache

I have a Laravel + Apache2 Setup with the following configuration:

```
...
<Directory "/var/www/laravel-app/current/public">
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
...
```

I want to lock it down so I added:

```
<Location />
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 1.2.3.4
        Require ip 5.6.7.8
    </RequireAny>
</Location>
```

But some API should be more open:

```
<Location "/api/some-api/v1.0/">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

This doesn't seem to work, apparently I also need to open up the "front controller" from the rewrite: index.php

```
<Location "/index.php">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Great, now it works but index.php is open for everyone.
What's the correct approach for something like this?
With Nginx servers we apparently don't have this problems, the location blocks each use the index.php via `try_files` and the index.php is still not reachable.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't remember a lot about Apache/Nginx and Laravel. From what I remember/know is that any URI that tries to use Laravel, will always get redirected to the `index.php` inside the `public` folder, that is why you have `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` and some other rules before it, so I think you are never reaching your desired URL `Location` config, because the main directory config changes it before hand

Comment: @matiaslauriti thank you, yes you seem to be right, rewrites seem to apply very early. The Location blocks definitely apply though, just in another order than I expected: 1. rewrite to index.php, 2. check the index.php Location Require, 3. check the actual URI Location Require of e.g. the /api. Very good to know but I still need to allow access to the index.php for everything. I locked it a bit further down: `<LocationMatch "^/index.php$">Require all granted</LocationMatch>` but still.

Comment: I guess another way would be to handle the URI + IP requirements as `RewriteCond` in the `Directory` block but that seems very... inelegant.

Comment: Another possibility is that you let Laravel handle rejections, but that would mean that unwanted requests already reached the system, so it "wastes" resources initializing the framework just to reject the request. Another possibility (depending on your infra) is that you have 2 web servers, one acts as a normal system and the other is a reverse proxy, so the normal system is hidden behind the reverse proxy, and that proxy will do this filtering for you, never ever even reaching your main server, but this is too complex/overengineered if you do not have a pool of serves for the proxy to talk to